# how to split comma separated values and store them in database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have a tableA with below format

```
fact_id | A-B_dim_id | a_vector| b
1       | 1234       |  1.25,2.25,3.25  | 1.5
```

and now i want to store them in a different table in the following format

```
fact_id | A-B_dim_id | a_vector_id|a_vector_value
anything| 1234       | 0          | 1.25
anything| 1234       | 1          | 2.25
anything| 1234       | 3          | 3.25
```

I do not have any control over the number of values in a vector it can range anywhere from 0 - 365 .

Please suggest me how to do this using SSIS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you derive a_vector_id. Is it just an incremented value? Would you be comfortable with a script component solution?

Comment: @jymbo: yes it is just incremental values the first value in the vector should have id as 0 and second should have 1 and so on. I have very little knowledge on coding so it will be very great ful if you provide me a solution without using a script task. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      [A-B_dim_id] INT
    , a_vector NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp ([A-B_dim_id], a_vector)
VALUES (1234, '1.25,2.25,3.25')

DECLARE @temp2 TABLE
(
      fact_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [A-B_dim_id] INT
    , a_vector_id SMALLINT
    , a_vector_value DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @temp2 ([A-B_dim_id], a_vector_id, a_vector_value)
SELECT 
      [A-B_dim_id]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [A-B_dim_id] ORDER BY 1/0)
    , t.c.value('.', 'DECIMAL(10,2)')
FROM (
     SELECT 
          [A-B_dim_id]
        , ID = CAST ('<t>' + REPLACE(a_vector, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
     FROM @temp
) r 
CROSS APPLY ID.nodes ('/t') t(c) 

SELECT * FROM @temp2
```

Output -

```
fact_id     A-B_dim_id  a_vector_id a_vector_value
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
1           1234        1           1.25
2           1234        2           2.25
3           1234        3           3.25
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Devart. Is there any way we can do the operation with SSIS?

Comment: Insert your results into temp table and after it try to export values from this table.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `UnPivotDelimitedString` custom transformation available on CodePlex (link below).

[UnPivotDelimitedString](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UnPivotDelimitedString)

I can't vouch for it being any good, but it appears that will help accomplish your task in SSIS.

Comment: Hi @Mike The result that is showed on the site is exactly what i wanted.But how to make it work.I mean after clicking download it downloaded a .dll file what should i do with it?

Comment: You need to add the custom componnt. Take is look at this blog: [reference](http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-add-ssis-custom-component-to.html). It has a pretty concise description on adding custom components. Or Google "ssis add custom component" for similar content.